# ListView with different layouts with two different objects

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I want to populate a ListView with different layouts for odd and even rows. It should look like this:

[image]

I use two objects "OddListItem" and "EvenListItem" to store/access the data. I do not know how to pass both objects to my custom listview adapter and get the correct view.

My object classes:

```
public class OddListItem {

    private String time_start;
    private String time_end;
    private String location;

    public OddListItem(String time_start, String time_end, String location) {
        super();
        this.time_start = time_start;
        this.time_end = time_end;
        this.location = location;
    }

    // getters and setters
    void setTimeStart(String time_start) {
        this.time_start = time_start;
    }

    void setTimeEnd(String time_end) {
        this.time_end = time_end;
    }

    void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getTimeStart() {
        return time_start;
    }

    public String getTimeEnd() {
        return time_end;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}

public class EvenListItem {

    private String image;
    private String location;

    public EvenListItem (String image, String location) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.location = location;
    }

    // getters and setters
    void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

MyCustomAdapter:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Tag for Logging
    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomAdapter";

    int type;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

    private ArrayList<OddListItem> mData = new ArrayList<OddListItem>();
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    //private TreeSet mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet();

    private Context context;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void addItem(final OddListItem item) {
        mData.add(item);
        //The notification is not necessary since the items are not added dynamically
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addSeparatorItem(final OddListItem item) {
        mData.add(item);
        //The notification is not necessary since the items are not added dynamically
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        /*if ((position%2) == 0){
            type = TYPE_ITEM;
        } else {
            type = TYPE_SEPARATOR;
        }
        return type;*/
        return position%2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public OddListItem getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    //inflate the new layout
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_list_row_odd, parent, false);
                    holder.tv_time_from = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_from);
                    holder.tv_time_to = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_to);
                    holder.tv_current_location_odd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_location_odd);
                    //fill the layout with values
                    /*holder.tv_time_from.setText("12:34");
                    holder.tv_time_to.setText("12:37");
                    holder.tv_current_location_odd.setText("Aktueller Standort");*/
                    holder.tv_time_from.setText(mData.get(position).getTimeStart());
                    holder.tv_time_to.setText(mData.get(position).getTimeEnd());
                    holder.tv_current_location_odd.setText(mData.get(position).getLocation());
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    //inflate the new layout
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_list_row_even, parent, false);
                    holder.tv_current_location_even = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_location_even);
                    holder.img_transport = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_transport);
                    //fill the layout with values
                    holder.tv_current_location_even.setText("Hauptbahnhof");
                    holder.img_transport.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rollator));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv_time_from;
        public TextView tv_time_to;
        public TextView tv_current_location_odd;
        public TextView tv_current_location_even;
        public ImageView img_transport;
    }
}
```

Here I generate the data and call the adapter:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detailed_connection);

    generateData();

    //fill ListView with custom content from MyCustomAdapter class
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    for (int i = 1; i < odd_items.size(); i++) {
        mAdapter.addItem(odd_items.get(i));
        if (i % 1 == 0) {
            mAdapter.addSeparatorItem(odd_items.get(i));
        }
    }
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    //set duration text
    tv_duration = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_duration);
    tv_duration.setText("Dauer: 22 Minuten");
}

private void generateData() {

    odd_items = new ArrayList<OddListItem>();
    odd_items.add(new OddListItem("12:34", "", "Aktueller Standort"));
    odd_items.add(new OddListItem("12:37", "12:37", "TUM"));
    odd_items.add(new OddListItem("12:42", "12:42", "Hauptbahnhof Nord"));
    odd_items.add(new OddListItem("12:48", "12:48", "Hauptbahnhof"));

    even_items = new ArrayList<EvenListItem>();
    even_items.add(new EvenListItem("R.drawable.rollator", "3 Minuten Fußweg"));
    even_items.add(new EvenListItem("R.drawable.bus", "Richtung Hauptbahnhof Nord"));
    even_items.add(new EvenListItem("R.drawable.rollator", "6 Minuten Fußweg"));

    mData = new Data(odd_items, even_items);
}
```

Any help would be great. Maybe there is also a better approach then please let me know.

Comment: what is wrong with the current code?

Comment: I have no access to my EvenListItem in the adapter. I do not know how to pass it to the adapter. I need both objects in my adapter

Comment: you can pass it to the constructor of adapter class and use it there

Comment: yes but how do I handle then the getCount(), addItem() and addSeperatorItem() methods in my adaper.

Comment: i would have 1 list add one more field 0 for odd and 1 more even

Comment: I am now able to access both objects in my adapter. But how do I implement getItem() and getItemId() from BaseAdapter as it can retunr only one object type?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59643/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-mr-mojo).

Comment: check the answer now with snap shot. customization i beleve you can do yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a Single list of Items

```
public class Items {


    private String time_start;
    private String time_end;
    private String location;
    private int image;
    private String locationeven;
    private int oddoreven;

    public String getTime_start() {
        return time_start;
    }
    public void setTime_start(String time_start) {
        this.time_start = time_start;
    }
    public String getTime_end() {
        return time_end;
    }
    public void setTime_end(String time_end) {
        this.time_end = time_end;
    }
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
    public int getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(int image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public String getLocationeven() {
        return locationeven;
    }
    public void setLocationeven(String locationeven) {
        this.locationeven = locationeven;
    }
    public int getOddoreven() {
        return oddoreven;
    }
    public void setOddoreven(int oddoreven) {
        this.oddoreven = oddoreven;
    }

}
```

In onCreate of Activity call

```
 generateData() ;
```

Then

```
 ArrayList<Items>  oddorevenlist = new ArrayList<Items>();
 private void generateData() {

           Items item1 = new Items();
           item1.setTime_start("12:34");
           item1.setTime_end("");
           item1.setLocation("Aktueller Standort");
           item1.setOddoreven(0);
           oddorevenlist.add(item1);

           Items item2 = new Items();
           item2.setImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           item2.setLocationeven("3 Minuten Fußweg");
           item2.setOddoreven(1);
           oddorevenlist.add(item2);

           Items item3 = new Items();
           item3.setTime_start("12:37");
           item3.setTime_end("12:37");
           item3.setLocation("Tum");
           item3.setOddoreven(0);
           oddorevenlist.add(item3);

           Items item4 = new Items();
           item4.setImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           item4.setLocationeven("Richtung Hauptbahnhof Nord");
           item4.setOddoreven(1);
           oddorevenlist.add(item4);

           Items item5 = new Items();
           item5.setTime_start("12:42");
           item5.setTime_end("12:42");
           item5.setLocation("Hauptbahnhof Nord");
           item5.setOddoreven(0);
           oddorevenlist.add(item5);

           Items item6 = new Items();
           item6.setImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
           item6.setLocationeven("R6 Minuten Fußweg");
           item6.setOddoreven(1);
           oddorevenlist.add(item6);

           Items item7 = new Items();
           item7.setTime_start("12:48");
           item7.setTime_end("12:48");
           item7.setLocation("HHauptbahnhof");
           item7.setOddoreven(0);
           oddorevenlist.add(item7);

           MyCustomAdapter mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,oddorevenlist);
           setListAdapter(mAdapter);

       }
```

Adapter code

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    // Tag for Logging
    private static final String TAG = "MyCustomAdapter";

    int type;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;



    private ArrayList<Items>  oddorevenlist ;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;


    private Context context;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Items> oddorevenlist) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.context = context;

        this.oddorevenlist = oddorevenlist;
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (oddorevenlist.get(position).getOddoreven()==0){
            type = TYPE_ITEM;
        } else if (oddorevenlist.get(position).getOddoreven()==1) {
            type = TYPE_SEPARATOR;
        }
        return type;

    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return oddorevenlist.size();
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "getView " + position + " " + convertView + " type = " + type);
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ITEM:
                    //inflate the new layout
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_odd, parent, false);
                    holder.tv_time_from = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_from);
                    holder.tv_time_to = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_to);
                    holder.tv_current_location_odd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_location_odd);

                    holder.tv_time_from.setText(oddorevenlist.get(position).getTime_start());
                    holder.tv_time_to.setText(oddorevenlist.get(position).getTime_end());
                    holder.tv_current_location_odd.setText(oddorevenlist.get(position).getLocation());
                    break;
                case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                    //inflate the new layout
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_even, parent, false);
                    holder.tv_current_location_even = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_current_location_even);
                    holder.img_transport = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_transport);
                    //fill the layout with values
                    holder.tv_current_location_even.setText(oddorevenlist.get(position).getLocationeven());
                    holder.img_transport.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv_time_from;
        public TextView tv_time_to;
        public TextView tv_current_location_odd;
        public TextView tv_current_location_even;
        public ImageView img_transport;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }


}
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: @Mr.Mojo welcome. note. R.drawable.ic_launcher is drawable. But in your case you had the field for the same as string

Comment: Thanks for the hint I just used this for testing.

Comment: The code mentioned in this example needs to be modified a little, otherwise you will find that the listview will have randomly repeating rows and the content might arbitrarily change upon scrolling. The solution is to get the right holder first - if the convertview is null then initializing the holder and setting a tag, otherwise getting the holder by tag. Only then you should proceed with filling the holder.

Comment: @user87049 yes that canbe modified with the right view holder pattern implementation. In a hurry i din't give much attention. Little tweak to the existing code will help.http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html